# VSCode Interactive syntax highlighting with Mono?

Tags: f#, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, f#-interactive, ionide

F# interactive in Visual Studio Code (with Ionide) has syntax highlighting by default on Windows 10. I just installed a Linux distro, and VSCode + Ionide doesn't show syntax highlights in the interactive terminal.

Any idea how to configure this? This is how it looks right now:

[image: No syntax highlight example]

Comment: Your screenshot appears to be showing the terminal window, not the code editor.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Thanks, Fyodor. The question was unclear so I've clarified it a bit; it is indeed the F# interactive terminal where I'm missing the syntax highlighting.

Comment: @Aphex, except maybe for errors (red), ionide doesn't provide syntax highlighting in the F# Interactive window.